# V4L2: Why image taken with shortest exposure-time looks way too brighter than auto-exposure mode?

Tags: images, camera, v4l

When capturing image using the default auto-exposure-mode:

```
$ v4l2-ctl -d0 --set-fmt-video=width=width,height=height,pixelformat=MJPG --stream-mmap --stream-to=auto_expo.jpg --stream-count=1
```

auto_expo.jpg shows:

[image]

But when capturing image using the manual exposure, using shortest possible exposure value of 4:

```
$ v4l2-ctl -d0 -c exposure_auto=1
$ v4l2-ctl -d0 -c exposure_absolute=4

$ v4l2-ctl -d0 --set-fmt-video=width=width,height=height,pixelformat=MJPG --stream-mmap --stream-to=manual_expo.jpg --stream-count=1
```

manual_expo.jpg shows

[image]

V4L2 Values Before:

```
$ v4l2-ctl -d0 --list-ctrls
                     brightness 0x00980900 (int)    : min=0 max=15 step=1 default=8 value=8
                       contrast 0x00980901 (int)    : min=0 max=15 step=1 default=8 value=8
                     saturation 0x00980902 (int)    : min=0 max=15 step=1 default=7 value=7
                            hue 0x00980903 (int)    : min=-10 max=10 step=1 default=0 value=0
 white_balance_temperature_auto 0x0098090c (bool)   : default=1 value=1
                          gamma 0x00980910 (int)    : min=1 max=10 step=1 default=7 value=7
                           gain 0x00980913 (int)    : min=0 max=0 step=0 default=0 value=0
           power_line_frequency 0x00980918 (menu)   : min=0 max=2 default=2 value=2
      white_balance_temperature 0x0098091a (int)    : min=2800 max=6500 step=1 default=2800 value=2800 flags=inactive
                      sharpness 0x0098091b (int)    : min=0 max=15 step=1 default=6 value=6
         backlight_compensation 0x0098091c (int)    : min=0 max=1 step=1 default=0 value=0
                  exposure_auto 0x009a0901 (menu)   : min=0 max=3 default=3 value=3
              exposure_absolute 0x009a0902 (int)    : min=4 max=5000 step=1 default=625 value=625 flags=inactive
                 focus_absolute 0x009a090a (int)    : min=0 max=21 step=1 default=16 value=16 flags=inactive
                     focus_auto 0x009a090c (bool)   : default=1 value=1
```

V4L2 Values After:

```
$ v4l2-ctl -d0 --list-ctrls

                     brightness 0x00980900 (int)    : min=0 max=15 step=1 default=8 value=8
                       contrast 0x00980901 (int)    : min=0 max=15 step=1 default=8 value=8
                     saturation 0x00980902 (int)    : min=0 max=15 step=1 default=7 value=7
                            hue 0x00980903 (int)    : min=-10 max=10 step=1 default=0 value=0
 white_balance_temperature_auto 0x0098090c (bool)   : default=1 value=1
                          gamma 0x00980910 (int)    : min=1 max=10 step=1 default=7 value=7
                           gain 0x00980913 (int)    : min=0 max=0 step=0 default=0 value=0
           power_line_frequency 0x00980918 (menu)   : min=0 max=2 default=2 value=2
      white_balance_temperature 0x0098091a (int)    : min=2800 max=6500 step=1 default=2800 value=2800 flags=inactive
                      sharpness 0x0098091b (int)    : min=0 max=15 step=1 default=6 value=6
         backlight_compensation 0x0098091c (int)    : min=0 max=1 step=1 default=0 value=0
                  exposure_auto 0x009a0901 (menu)   : min=0 max=3 default=3 value=1
              exposure_absolute 0x009a0902 (int)    : min=4 max=5000 step=1 default=625 value=4
                 focus_absolute 0x009a090a (int)    : min=0 max=21 step=1 default=16 value=16 flags=inactive
                     focus_auto 0x009a090c (bool)   : default=1 value=1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
exposure_absolute 0x009a0902 (int)    : min=4 max=5000 step=1 default=625 value=4
```

This is showing that exposures from **1/4** second to **1/5000** second are available.  You have actually chosen the longest (4=>¼) exposure, not the shortest.

Comment: No, when I increase "exposure_absolute" image becomes more brighter.

Answer (score 1):

Does the camera have by chance a OV5640 chip?
I could exactly reproduce your described behaviour with such a camera chip on a Linux system.

Strange thing: The same camera has no brightness setting issues at all on a Windows system using `AForge.Video.DirectShow`.

Since `v4l2-ctl` get/set exposure properties work pretty well with other cameras, the root cause seems to be a `v4l2-ctl` implementation issue with the OV5640 chip, somehow the min/max range is likely screwed up.